# Some advices to create ToggleButton

Tags: android, togglebutton

I have to create `ToggleButton` like this one (should be resized on any device).

And then layout it in `ViewGroup`'s `onLayout` method.

Could you please provide me any ideas how to create it?

[image]

---

I tried to do it in this way:

**buttons.xml**

```xml
<ToggleButton
        android:id="@id/add_favorites_button_id"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/menu_button_selector"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/star"
        android:textOff=""
        android:textOn=""
        android:contentDescription="Add Favorites"/>
```

**menu_button_selector.xml**

```xml
<level-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:maxLevel="0">
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:state_checked="true">
            <rotate
                    android:fromDegrees="90"
                    android:toDegrees="90"
                    android:pivotX="50%"
                    android:pivotY="50%"
                    android:drawable="@drawable/round_button_active"/>
        </item>
        <item android:state_checked="false">
            <rotate
                    android:fromDegrees="90"
                    android:toDegrees="90"
                    android:pivotX="50%"
                    android:pivotY="50%"
                    android:drawable="@drawable/round_button"/>
        </item>

    </selector>
</item>
.....
</level-list>
```

**round_button_active.xml**

I have some background and just rotate it. Because buttons should locate in known degrees: 0, 45, 90, ...

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:topLeftRadius="50dp" android:topRightRadius="50dp"/>
        <solid android:color="@color/tb_red_button"/>
        <size android:width="60dp" android:height="60dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

And then in `onLayout` method I layout it:

```java
final View button = parentLayout.getChildAt(i);
button.getBackground().setLevel(i);
button.setOnClickListener(this);
button.layout(x1, y1, x2, y2);
```

**What I received:**

[image]

on 0, 90, 180, etc degrees buttons looks fairly clear to what they shoukd be

but

on 45, 135, etc degrees button is cut by rectangle canvas. Even I rotate it I do it in scope on rectangle canvas.

Comment: I would start by creating your own custom viewgroup and then create a custom togglebutton

Comment: Yes, thank you very much for good advice. The best one

Comment: Maybe the custom togglebutton isnt needed ;)

Comment: Yes, you are right, sorry, I have spent really a lot time creating it (all the time wrong), that's why I responded to you answer like so ;)

Comment: Good luck! Because creating custom components isn't the easiest thing on Android

Comment: Please let me know if i understood your requirement correctly or not. The red circle should travel from left upper side to right upper side, on click, following/traveling through the path bounded by two semi-circles with black circumference.

Comment: @Kaustuv, looks like correctly, this should be a button (with all events like ToggleButton has) with the same view in any place between semicircles. I updated the required image.

Answer (score 0):

From what i understood, one possible way to achieve this (using images) will be like

Consider the image that you have here as semi-circle (the two black border semi-circles), which is a part of full circle. The upper half of this circle is transparent. This whole setup will be an image inside an image-view.

The red circle thumb is also an image which has same size as the above setup, has all of area as transparent except for the red color part. Put this in another image-view

Now place both image-view one above the other, with red one on top. Add click listener to red image-view and rotate it using `imageView.setRotate(degree)`

For giving a rotation movement like feel, just call above method after very short interval and incrementing the value of degree each time.

I am adding an image for better understanding. The blue border is boundary of black cirle image-view and green border is boundary of red circle image-view. both have a common center, so that when upper image-view is rotated it will give an appearance of red circle following the path between the two black circle.

[image: two image views one above the other]

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. But is any possibility to create such background for button (using shapes, without images) with different sizes. Because of this should be applied for devices with different resolutions. The problem is that button's canvas is a rectangle. And when I rotate button's background - angles are visible.

Comment: Why u wanna use button? use image-views and set click listener on that. user won't notice the difference. In one image-view u can set two drawables, one each for background and src. These will form your two black circles. for red one use another image-view as i mentioned in my answer above. And yes you can draw circular shapes in xml and place in drawable folder. Use different xml for different circles. Please note that green and blue boundary are just indicators of size n shape of image-views, they won't be visible.